# Python - Create multidimensional array like in R

Tags: python, arrays, r, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a multidimensional array of 5 dimensions like the "array" function in R but in Python.

Here is my array function in R

```
myarray <- array(0,dim=c(A,B,C,D,E))
```

A=10, B=5, C=22, D=4 and E=2.

You can find an R image with the expected array as output in the following link

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bkp10w62bb2xsqg/AABsFh5qv_7E5wLbg_Iux3jka?dl=0

Thanks.

Raúl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
myshape = (10,5,22,4,2) 
myarray = np.zeros(myshape)
```

Answer (score 1):

In python you can create a dictionary like :

```
    a = {'A':[],'B':[],'C':[],'D':[],'E':[]}
```

you can also use list inside list, but dictionary is more efficient way of storing the data.